# Determine the basis of the kernel and the image (matrix). But that's not the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, f(x) = Ax$, where $A=
> \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\  4 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$
>
> Determine the basis of the kernel $Ker(f)$ and the basis of the image
>   $Im(f)$.

But I think it's enough if I just do it for one of these because it's actually the same..?

I transpose matrix $A$: $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4\\ 
2 & 5\\ 
3 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$ then I form it with Gauss (don't check for inaccuracies, it's correct) and get $\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 24\\ 
0 & 12\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.

I transpose it back: $\begin{pmatrix}
6  & 0  & 0\\ 
24 & 12 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Thus $Im(f)= span\left(\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
6\\ 
24
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
12
\end{pmatrix}\right\}\right)$, so Basis $B= \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
6\\ 
24
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
12
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$

and that's also a basis of the kernel, isn't it?

Comment: The kernel is a subset of the domain, so a subset of $\mathbb R^3$. The image is a subset of the codomain $\mathbb R^2$. So, no, they’re not the same thing at all.

Comment: @amd Ok thank you for info, but I did the basis for the image correctly? All the formings with Gauss surely are.

Comment: Yes, your basis for the image is correct, though it might help you if you went further than just row-echelon-form and instead went to reduced-row-echelon-form.  I think the basis $\{\binom{1}{0},\binom{0}{1}\}$ looks a lot cleaner, don't you?

Comment: @JMoravitz But how did you get these as basis? If the solution is not too long please show.

Comment: By the same method you were following except I went further and got it to [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) instead of stopping partway through the calculations.  There is nothing incorrect about stopping as soon as you've discovered all of the pivot locations, and it can save you time to not go any further, but with a small bit of extra effort you might have a simpler basis to use.  The remaining missing steps could have been for example divide second row by $12$, then subtract $24$ times the second row from the first row, then divide first row by $6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaussian elimination on $A$ gives
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & -3 & -6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which allows us to conclude that a basis for the image of $f$ is
$$
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}2\\5\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
However, since the matrix has rank $2$, any basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ would do.

Backwards elimination goes on as
$$
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which allows us to say that a basis of the kernel is
$$
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$

Note that the image and the kernel live in different vector spaces, so they can't have the same basis.

With your method you're essentially doing column elimination, which certainly gives you a basis for the image. However, this cannot be used for going on and getting a basis for the kernel.

If instead you proceed with elimination on the matrix, the columns in the original matrix corresponding to the pivot column in the row echelon form give a basis for the image.

When you arrive to the reduced row echelon form, it's also easy to read off from it a basis for the kernel.

How do you do it? Interpret the RREF as the matrix of a homogeneous system; in our case it is
\begin{cases}
x_1-x_3=0\\
x_2+2x_3=0
\end{cases}
so we can give the value $x_3=1$ and compute the values for $x_1$ and $x_2$.

If the RREF is, for instance,
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
the linear system is
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1+2x_2-x_4=0\\
x_3+3x_4=0
\end{cases}
$$
The free variables are $x_2$ and $x_4$, so we consider the vectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix}? \\ 1 \\ ? \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}? \\ 0 \\ ? \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $?$ denotes the value to be computed from the system. These two vectors are certainly linearly independent (why?). Thus we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -3 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
as the vectors forming a basis for the kernel.

Comment: Great answer helped me a lot thank you.